# IntelliJ/WebStorm: Split editor so that splits stay together

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I would like to split a tab (either horizontally or vertically) so that there is still only one tab for that file so that when I switch to other tab or file, those panes will go away but when I come back to the file, panes show up (similar to how Eclipse works).

Currently when I split tab, those two tabs are completely detached so that when I go to other file in one group, split tab still stays put in other group.

Comment: That's not possible in IDEA. There is no "in tab" / "in editor" split. Only "a new tab in a separate (split) area" (in other words: open the same file more than once at the same time).

Comment: That's disappointing but thank you for the reply. I will try to create a feature request.

Comment: Please do: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA (if implemented it will be available in all IDEs, so makes sense making such a request straight in the IDEA tracker (if done in WebStorm's one it will be moved here anyway)). If you make such a request, please post a link back here (I want to star/watch it).

Comment: Feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-306398/Provide-ability-to-create-split-panes-within-an-editor-tab

Comment: Thanks. I've checked the ticket. Based on the description there, I think you may be interested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-12130/Editor-Groups and related tickets. Have a look (I think they should be related to your request).

Comment: Thx for the reference. That ticket opened 16 years ago so don't have any confidence that those features will be implemented in our work life :)